# i'm using a select tag in my laravel project but when i select it's not taking any value from option

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to fetch data from database after selecting from the select tag.

this is my view code:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Name</label>
        <select name="id" class="form-control">
            @foreach($clients as $client)
                <option value="{{ $client->Cid }}" {{ $selectedclients == $client->Cid ? selected="selected" : '' }}>{{ $client->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my controller code:

```php
$Clients = Client::all();
$selectedClients = Client::first()->Cid;
```

when i run my code i'm getting the following error:

> Syntax error, unexpected '=' (View: /home/prasanna/Billing-master/resources/views/Qtcreate.blade.php).

Comment: which line in your code is unexpected '='? is that line you pasted?

Comment: thank you for your time. it's showing in the line of <option> tag @Kusy

Comment: @prasannapurohit could you please one answer as the answer please

Answer (score 3):

You forgot quotations around `selected="selected"` in this line:

```
<option value="{{ $client->Cid }}" {{ $selectedclients == $client->Cid ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $client->name }}</option>
```

Comment: hey thank you for your response when i did that i got error "Undefined variable: selectedclients" @dparoli

Comment: You have to pass `$selectedclients` from the controller to the view as you do with the `$clients` variable. I solved the error you first asked, this is another one.

Comment: actually that "{{$client -> Cid}}" should be  "{{$clients->Cid}}". but thank you, you gave me the exact idea about my mistake.

Comment: hey @dparoli. as your code befor it was working fine. when i did refresh i'm getting error as "Property [Cid] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: @foreach($clients as $client)
          <option value="{{ $clients->Cid }}" {{ $selectedclients == $client->Cid ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $client->name }}</option>
          @endforeach. in this line only i'm getting that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196966/discussion-between-prasanna-purohit-and-dparoli).

Comment: Change `$clients->Cid` to `$client->Cid` and accept the answer please.

Comment: Undefined variable: selectedclients (View: /home/prasanna/Billing-master/resources/views/Qtcreate.blade.php)
 this is error in this line:-    <?php $__currentLoopData = $clients; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $client): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
          <option value="<?php echo e($client->Cid); ?>" <?php echo e($selectedclients == $client->Cid ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>><?php echo e($client->name); ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>

Comment: please I don't want to debug all of your code, I usually get paid for that, you have some errors and I think I have answered correct to the original question and gave you advices for the others. If you have others error please post a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

//Call your model in controller

```
use App\Client;
```

In your controller do like this

//fetch values from db

```
$Clients = Client::all();
```

//pass it to view

```
return view('welcome', compact('Clients’));
```

// Then in your view

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
    <option value="{{ $client->Cid }}"
            @if ($selectedclients == $client->Cid)
            selected
            @endif

    >{{ $client->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you for answer. i had tried its saying that Undefined variable: selectedclients

Comment: @prasannapurohit `$selectedclients` it also available in your code. Do you pass that value from the controll

Comment: sorry for late reply can you share code to pass the value from control @Nipun Tharuksha

Comment: @PrasannaPurohit do you mean code in the controller to pass the $selectedclients

Comment: @prasannapurohit if you need more help please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can use selected attribute without value.

Try this

```
<option value="{{ $client->Cid }}" {{ $selectedclients == $client->Cid ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $client->name }}</option>
```

Look at your variable names in controller and view

In Controller :   $Clients & $selectedClients - In View :   $clients & $selectedclients